# How to set default value of not exposed parameter with GSON

Tags: kotlin, gson

I'm trying to use retrofit via GSON to parse this kind of json in Kotlin :

```
{
     "status":"ready"
     "users":
     [
         {
            "full_name":"user1",
            "id":1
         },
         {
            "full_name":"user2",
            "id":2
         }
     ]
}
```

I need to get the user list, so I've a retrofit request getting an instance of the class defined this way :

```
data class Info(var status:String, var users : List<User>)
```

And here's the request :

```
@GET("info")
fun getInfo(): Flowable<Info>
```

And this is the user class :

```
data class User (val full_name:String = "",
                 val id:Int = 0)
```

The issue is that when the full_name is not in the json, the field full_name of the user is set to null instead of "".

Meaning : the default value is ignored.

However if I set the default value of the info field "status" to "", it work : when status is not defined in the json, the Info instance created has its parameter "status" set to ""

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the example I gave was working. 
In my actual code, I hadn't init all the variables... Seems to be an issue for GSON...

TL;DR 
If you want a default value to be taken into account by GSON, you have to set all your exposed variable default values

Comment: Thanks, i still don't undestand why they implemented it like this. Lost a good hour trying to understand what was i doing wrong.